# POST request failing -React Application

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, web-development-server

please see codes:
I think the code is logical but there is something wrong with front end 'onFinish' function. I have checked the api routes and they seem ok.. so slightly confused

```
register frontend page (Route: users)

    const router = require('express').Router()
const User = require('../models/usersModel')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

// Register new User
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.send({
        message: 'User already on database',
        success: false,
        data: null,
      })
    }

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    req.body.password = hashedPassword
    const newUser = new User(req.body)
    await newUser.save()
    res.send({
      message: 'New user created successfully',
      success: true,
      data: null,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({
      message: error.message,
      success: false,
      data: null,
    })
  }
})
module.exports = router
```

userRoute (backend):

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const User = require('../models/usersModel')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

// Register new User
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.send({
        message: 'User already on database',
        success: false,
        data: null,
      })
    }

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    req.body.password = hashedPassword
    const newUser = new User(req.body)
    await newUser.save()
    res.send({
      message: 'New user created successfully',
      success: true,
      data: null,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({
      message: error.message,
      success: false,
      data: null,
    })
  }
})
module.exports = router
```

userModel (backend):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', userSchema)
```

server.js(backend)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
require('dotenv').config()
const dbConfig = require('./config/dbConfig')

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.use(express.json())

const usersRoute = require('./routes/usersRoute')

app.use('/api/users', usersRoute)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`))
```

package.json

```
  {
  "name": "mernbus",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "react-process-env": "^0.1.0"
  },
  "proxy": "https://localhost:5000/"
}
```

ISSUE:

when registering the new user. I am getting meesage 404 not found.
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/users/register
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issue that **NO** frontend code is shared!

I see that the default port is 5000 if you have not supplied a port number 3000 as an env variable to your script running this server (not mentioned in question).

If that would be the case, then you need to change
`http://localhost:3000/api/users/register`
to
`http://localhost:5000/api/users/register`

Comment: How can I share the source code?
App is not connecting to MongoDB for some reason.. so I think the  front end can not send the data to backend!!

Comment: further more why below code is showing error for useNavigate() object creation? I hvae imported it right.. 

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

function protectedRoute() {
  const { loading, setLoading } = useState(true)
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const validateToken = () => {
    try {
      const response = axios.post(
        '/api/users/get-user-by-id',
        {},
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}` },
        }
      )

Comment: if (response.status) {
        setLoading(false)
      } else {
        setLoading(false)
        navigate('/login')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false)
      navigate('/login')
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      validateToken()
    } else {
      navigate('/login')
    }
  }, [])

  return
  ;<div>{loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <>{children}</>}</div>
}

export default protectedRoute

Comment: sorry bit ctrl+K was not working for pasting code

Comment: this is the error stack
src\components\protectedRoute.js
  Line 6:35:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "protectedRoute" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"     react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: Line 7:20:  React Hook "useNavigate" is called in function "protectedRoute" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: Line 30:3:  React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "protectedRoute" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"    react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: @arshaikh0171 You can only call hooks inside a functional component or a custom hook like `useCustomHook`. It seems you're trying to use hooks inside a function "protectedRoute" is not the way it should be used.

//functional component
const FuncComp = (props) => {
  useEffect(...);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
}

or 

// custom hook
const useCustomNavigate = (args) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
}

Comment: Also, unrelated to this, coming back to your main question,
when you run your mongo server, do you get affirmative message from server
`App listening on port: {Port}` ? Because if not, then sending request to that endpoint will not work either from browser, frontend or any API platform like postman, etc.